# Persistant variable with Gmail scripting (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, google-apps

I have a Google Apps script that runs every minute, performing tasks on Gmail messages.

**How to have a persistant variable that I can access on subsequent calls of the script `main.gs`?**

I just need a simple `int` variable like:

```
var lastaction = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
```

Then, during the next call of `main.gs`, I need to check several things based on the date + elapsed time since the last action (even if the script is run every minute, an action is *not* necessarily performed every minute).

Note: I've already read [Persistant variable in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039988/persistant-variable-in-google-apps-script) but it seems a bit complicated for this simple task here (just keep an integer timestamp of the last action done by a previous call of the script)

Comment: Complicated or not, that's the only way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @TheMaster. This is the final goal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60773329/run-a-gmail-google-apps-script-daily-at-800-1230-1700. Would you have any idea?