# Run a Gmail Google Apps Script daily at 8:00, 12:30, 17:00

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-apps

I need to run a Google Apps script three times a day: at 8:00, 12:30, 17:00.

**How to do this?**

I have already looked at `Triggers`, and more specifically `Time driven`:

- Hour timer, but `Every hour`, `Every 2 hours`, `Every 4 hours` are not adapted here
- Day timer, but then `8am to 9am` is not very precise, I would prefer something more precise, and also 12:30 is not possible
- Specific time, but then `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` is not adapted to run it daily

`From calendar` triggers does not seem adapted either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [nearMinute() and atHour()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#nearMinute(Integer)):

```
const createTrigger = ([hour, minute])=>
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(hour)
  .nearMinute(minute)  
  .everyDays(1) 
  .create();

[[8,0],[12,30],[17,0]].forEach(createTrigger)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @TheMaster. PS: where is the natural place to put such "init" / "setup" / "doitonce" code? Just in a `function setup() { }` that you manually run once, in the same .gs file than the main `myFunction` (the one that does the job)?

Comment: @Bas Yes. You could add ui menu `setup` to run this `setup` function

Comment: Thank you. Where would this UI menu appear (would you have a screenshot)?

Comment: @Basj Apologies.  Menus aren't available to gmail add ons(They're only available to sheets/docs..). May be try [homepages or cards](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail)

Comment: @MariosKaramanis One advantage I can think of for your answer seems to be  the  `everyDays` is not compulsory.A possible solution in my case would be to have  frequency `n` infinitely higher -not sure it'll work.

Comment: @TheMaster it will definitely work. You just need to delete the previous triggers everytime you run it. setTrigger() can be ran weekly or monthly or whatever.

Answer (score 10):

Although the TheMaster's answer is correct I would like to elaborate a little bit on an alternative approach which might be useful for future readers and different projects.

Let's say you have a list of **specific** times (24H:mm) you want to schedule every day:

```
var times = [[9,30],[9,45],[10,00],[12,00]] // 9:30 am, 9:45 am, 10:00 am 12:00pm
```

which can be completely **random**, following any sequence you like.

As you can see in the code below, you can run the `setTrigger()` function , to generate a **scheduled** trigger  of another function `function_Triggered()` for each element in the aforementioned list. The trigger will have the time provided in `times` and the date of **today**.

If you want to perform this task **everyday**, then you just need to create a daily trigger for `setTrigger()` and run it **before the earliest time** in `times`. In this case, you are generating triggers everyday, and therefore `deleteTriggers()` is used to delete the previous (disabled) triggers for `function_Triggered()` that are attached to your project.

```
function setTrigger() {

deleteTriggers();  
var times = [[9,30],[9,45],[10,00],[12,00]]; // 9:30 am, 9:45 am, 10:00 am 12:00pm
times.forEach(t_el => scheduledTrigger(t_el[0],t_el[1]));
}

function scheduledTrigger(hours,minutes){
  
var today_D = new Date();  
var year = today_D.getFullYear();
var month = today_D.getMonth();
var day = today_D.getDate();
  
pars = [year,month,day,hours,minutes];
  
var scheduled_D = new Date(...pars);
var hours_remain=Math.abs(scheduled_D - today_D) / 36e5;
ScriptApp.newTrigger("function_Triggered")
.timeBased()
.after(hours_remain * 60 *60 * 1000)
.create()
}

function deleteTriggers() {
  
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
  if (   triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "function_Triggered") {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
}
}

function function_Triggered() {
 // your function code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

soMario and TheMaster have working solutions, but unfortunately for my use case I needed some tighter tolerances than the + or - 15 minutes!! Which the google app script scheduler 'works' upon.

I used their very inaccurate scheduler to run the below function every 5 minutes. This function will check current time very accurately, it seems so far, and only run the next 'core' function within your desired hours and minutes. A simple if condition addition, using getDay() will add a day of week 'filter'.

```
function timeCheck() {
  var nowH=new Date().getHours();
  var nowM=new Date().getMinutes();
  Logger.log('Hour: '+nowH+'  Minute: '+nowM)

  if (nowH = 1 && nowM < 12) { getStatus() }
  if (nowH = 10 && (nowM > 15 && nowM < 27)) { getStatus() }

  return
}
```