# Run script every 30 minutes from 9 am to 12 pm with triggers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code to run the code every Monday at `9am`. But I want to run the code every `30` minutes starting from `9 am` until `12 pm`

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction').timeBased().everyWeeks(1).onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY).atHour(9).create()
```

Can someone help me how can I be doing this with trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60773743/11225291) to achieve your goal.

Create an array of the desired times and iteratively create a weekly trigger for each of the times for Monday.

### Solution:

Execute **once** the `createTrigger` function to create the desired triggers for `myFunction`.

```
function createTrigger(){

const createTrigger = ([hour, minute])=>
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(hour)
  .nearMinute(minute)  
  .everyWeeks(1)
  .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
  .create();

[[9,0],[9,30],[10,0],[10,30],[11,0],[11,30],[12,0]].forEach(createTrigger);

}

function myFunction(){

// code you want to execute

}
```